# Is there a tool to transform html text into a single php variable keeping tabs and linebreaks?

Tags: php, html, variables, text

I need the same html-text in different places of my script so I want to save my html text in a php variable. Kinda like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
   <p>bla</p>
</div>
```

-->php:

```
$html="<div>\n\t<p>bla</p>\n</div>";
```

There are already some tools like [this](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/HTML_converter/) which transforms html text into multiple lines of php echo code. Is there also a tool for a more compact solution like in my example?

Comment: [heredoc](http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or nowdoc formats for strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`NOWDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (available since PHP 5.3.0) formatting to store the text:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div>
   <p>bla</p>
</div>
HTML;
```

If you want to use variables in your text, then you can use [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
   <p>{$variable}</p>
</div>
HTML;
```

See also: [Advantages / inconveniences of heredoc vs nowdoc in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11153049/1438393)

Comment: Awesome! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! But how could I embed a php echo command (with a function) inside my html text? I got this code: <?php echo plugins_url('plugin_name/img/filename.png'); ?> within my html text. Replacing <?php ?> with {} did not work.

Comment: oh lol. solved it with $variable=plugins_url('plugin_name/img/filename.png'); - with using $variable in the html text it was parsed