# Using multiple quotations in PHP codes

Tags: php

Let's say this is my script down here, as you can see I've used multiple " and '. These quotations conflict in ending the current php variable, so it basically sees this:

```
$message = "<?php echo '<div class="
```

As a string, whilst the quotation is only to define the class, not to end the variable. I've tried using ' but then it conflicts with the echo, so I'm kinda stuck at the moment.

```
    <?php

    $message = "
    <?php
    echo '<div class="gebruiker">';
    $fh = fopen('_gebruiker.txt','r');
            while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
              echo($line);
            }
            fclose($fh);
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
    ";

**MORE PHP CODE HERE**

?>
```

How can I use multiple quotations in one PHP script without them having conflicts.

Comment: seems like you're doing scary stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you use single quotes outside, you need to escape all single quotes inside, but can use double quotes and the dollar char without escaping.
- If you use double quotes outside, you need to escape all double quotes and dollar chars inside, but can use single quotes without escaping.
- If you use a heredoc string, you need to escape dollar chars but can use both single and double quotes without escaping.
- If you use a nowdoc string, you do not need to escape anything unless you have `FOO;` in the string at the beginning of a new line.

So the solution is to use a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) string:

```
$message = <<<'EOF'
your stuff with " or ' or $ here!
EOF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a backslash so PHP can recognize just only double quotes or quotes when escaped.

Example:

```
echo "<div class=\"gebruiker\">";
```

Comment: Escape orgies result in rather unreadable code. Also, he needs to escape variables, too, if he's using double quotes.

Comment: This is the easiest way he can use it. Also, there other ways we can treat it. But for a specific simple line, escaping with backslash suits better. You just cannot disregard my answer and this option.

Comment: I agree with @ThiefMaster, still this is an easy solution, for an asked question that has some flaws in its approach (IMHO).

Comment: But he cannot use that solution! His example string contains single quotes and dollars, so he at least needs to escape the dollars, too...

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes that is true, the variable $fh was not taken in the code, it simply removes it. Still looking for a solution for that, but atleast I got one of the problems solved now

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using either Heredoc or Nowdoc

#### Example

```
$foo = 'test';

// Heredoc
$here = <<<HERE
I'm here, $foo!
HERE;

// Nowdoc
$now = <<<'NOW'
I'm now, $foo!
NOW;
```

Heredoc will print the contents of $foo when echoed while Nowdoc will simply echo $foo.

In the references I added below you can do more reading up on this subject.

References:

- [php.net - strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)
- [stackoverflow - advantages of heredoc vs nowdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153049/advantages-inconveniences-of-heredoc-vs-nowdoc-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quotes with a slash character like so: `\"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you can't open Php tag without closing before.

```
<?php

$message = '<div class="gebruiker">';
$fh = fopen('_gebruiker.txt','r');
        while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
          $message .=$line.'<br/>';
        }
        fclose($fh);
$message.='</div>';
echo $message;
**MORE PHP CODE HERE**
?>
```