# Failed to write sql code with php into new php file

Tags: php, html, sql

Hy Guys i always fail when i try to write with php to an other php file...
It always delete me the $con and $result in the new file but why?
Thanks in advance!

Tried to write with fwrite($newfile, $txt);
fclose($newfile); into a php file but failed...

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect(\"localhost\",\"dbuser\",\"pw\",\"db\");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo \"Failed to connect to MySQL: \" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,\"SELECT * FROM me where me_genre like '%$var7%' LIMIT 6\");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo \"</div>\";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

$con and $result doesn't show up in new file...

Comment: Please remove all slashes from your code, they are useless.

Comment: I assume this is a text literal which is why the slashes are there - BUT also it is probably doing variable substitution and replacing what it thinks are variables.  You will need to escape all of the `$` for the variables - `\$con` etc.

Comment: Then i get a 500 error

Comment: @Nigel i will try it one second

Comment: @Nigel it works now awesome thank you!! Now i tried it with echo \"<div class=\"relatemovie\">\"; but it shows up as echo "<div class="relatemovie">"; and gives me again an error

Comment: How are you creating this string?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153049/advantages-inconveniences-of-heredoc-vs-nowdoc-in-php may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You like condition `'%$var7%'`  is wrong

For build a valid ike condition  ..you should use   concat

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM me 
  where me_genre like caoncat('%',$var7, '%') 
  LIMIT 6
```

You should not use  php in sql code  you are at risk for sqliject  for this you should 
  take a look at prepared  statement and binding param

```
$sql=   "SELECT * 
  FROM me 
  where me_genre like caoncat('%', ? , '%') 
  LIMIT 6";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","pw","db");

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$var7);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Apart from not using bind variables - there is nothing wrong with their original LIKE clause.